# Help identifying this bonsai tree

Tags: identification, bonsai

I received this bonsai tree as a gift, but as an absolute beginner I have been unable to identify its species using online guides. I hope one of you can help me out here, so I can care for it appropriately.

[image: bonsai tree]

Comment: Could you please confirm whether a leaf from this plant, when crushed between your fingers, gives off an aromatic smell?

Answer (score 3):

It is *Podocarpus*. I had a bonsai from this species too, but unfortunately died after 2 years. So it is not an easy one to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I vote Callistemon or Bottle brush as your Bonsai;  [Bottle brush Bonsai](http://www.bonsaitreegardener.net/types/flowering-bottlebrush)